# difference between character set and national character set oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

difference between character set and national character set oracle?

Answer (score 2):

This is answered in Oracle's documentation: [Choosing a Character Set](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch2charset.htm#NLSPG002)

> ## Character Set Encoding
>
> When computer systems process characters, they use numeric codes instead of the graphical representation of the character. For example, when the database stores the letter A, it actually stores a numeric code that the computer system interprets as the letter. These numeric codes are especially important in a global environment because of the potential need to convert data between different character sets.

> ## What is an Encoded Character Set?
>
> You specify an encoded character set when you create a database.
> Choosing a character set determines what languages can be represented
> in the database. It also affects:
>
> - How you create the database schema
> - How you develop applications that process character data
> - How the database works with the operating system
> - Database performance
> - Storage required for storing character data
>
> A group of characters (for example, alphabetic characters, ideographs,
> symbols, punctuation marks, and control characters) can be encoded as
> a character set. An encoded character set assigns a unique numeric
> code to each character in the character set. The numeric codes are
> called code points or encoded values. The following table shows
> examples of characters that have been assigned a hexadecimal code
> value in the ASCII character set.

> ## Choosing a National Character Set
>
> The term national character set refers to an alternative character set that enables you to store Unicode character data in a database that does not have a Unicode database character set. Another reason for choosing a national character set is that the properties of a different character encoding scheme may be more desirable for extensive character processing operations.
>
> SQL `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2`, and `NCLOB` data types support Unicode data only. You can use either the `UTF8` or the `AL16UTF16` character set. The default is `AL16UTF16`.
>
> Oracle recommends using SQL `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, and `CLOB` data types in `AL32UTF8` database to store Unicode character data. Use of SQL `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2`, and `NCLOB` should be considered only if you must use a database whose database character set is not `AL32UTF8`.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you have these two character sets mainly for historical reasons. In earlier times a typical setup was

- Character Set: `US7ASCII`
- National Character Set: `WE8ISO8859P1`

The character set was used for the generic part of your application. Then for your customers over all countries in the world you set the National Character Set according to the customer local requirement.

Nowadays with Unicode (i.e. `AL32UTF8`) there is actually no reason to use the National Character Set any more. More and more new native Oracle functions even do not support the National Character Set at all.

The only reason could be a heavy use of Asian characters where `AL16UTF16` is more efficient in terms of space.